# fastest way to send notification to all user laravel

Tags: laravel, notifications

I am building an app in laravel where I send a mail notification to all users once a new channel I create. So far I am using

```
$users=User::all();
 \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::send($users,new NewChannel($channel));
```

To send a notification to all users. Is there any package or way that would make the process faster? It is already taking years just with 5 users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into [queues](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#introduction) to make the request more responsive, though it will take the same time to process the mails but it will happen in background. Another approach would be to use a third party service like [sendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/laravel/) to take away the processing from your end.